# Is there a way to send an image and text field items from react js(hooks) to spring boot api endpoint with the same url at the same time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring-boot, react-hooks, material-ui

this is the spring boot API endpoint which receives request from react js frontend

```
@PostMapping(value = "/upload", consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, 
MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
public ResponseEntity<MessageResponse> uploadFile(@RequestPart("fileDB") String fileDB, 
@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file) {
  String message = "";
  try {
    storageService.store(file, fileDB);

    message = "Uploaded the file successfully: " + file.getOriginalFilename();
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(new MessageResponse(message));
  } catch (Exception e) {
    message = "Could not upload the file: " + file.getOriginalFilename() + "!";
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED).body(new 
 MessageResponse(message));
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can we use multipart and @RequestBody together in spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40924649/can-we-use-multipart-and-requestbody-together-in-spring)

Comment: the endpoint above works, I actually needed the frontend react side, how to push the elements from react.

Comment: when I use postman, am actually able to post both image and json data

Comment: Very similar to this question that I answered recently: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71006941/107976

Comment: const upload = (file, fileDB, onUploadProgress) => {
 
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', file);
  formData.append('fileDB', fileDB);

  return axios.post(`${API_URL}upload`, formData, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    },
    onUploadProgress
  });
};

Comment: this is how am trying to post but only file contents is sent, the other fields in 'res'  are hitting the table with blank values